# Why is google apps script changing my user property to some random code every time I save it?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am creating an editor add-on for google sheets and I'm currently stumped on why my user property (`MY_WEBHOOK`) is being changed every time I try to save it with `setProperty` to this code:

```js
function(){var L=h(fb(arguments));if(b&32)Vd(function(){a.apply(g||this,L)});else return m(a.apply(g||this,L))}
```

Here is the code I am using:

`code.gs`:

```js
function saveSettings(url) {
  PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty('MY_WEBHOOK', url);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Saved")
}

function getSettings() {
  return PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty('MY_WEBHOOK');
}
```

In my html file:

```html
<body onload="get()">

 <form>
    
    <label>What is the URL?</label>
    <input id="webhook-url" type="url" autofocus required placeholder="Webhook Here">
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="save()">
    
    <script>
    function save() {
       var url = document.getElementById('webhook-url').value
       google.script.run.saveSettings(url)
       alert(url)
       alert(google.script.run.getSettings)
       google.script.host.close()
    }
    
    function get() {
       var settings = google.script.run.getSettings
       document.getElementById('webhook-url').value = settings;
    }
    </script>
    
  </form>
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Modification points:

I think that there are 2 modification points in your script.

1. About `google.script.run.getSettings`, in this case, the function of `getSettings` is not run. Please add `()` like `google.script.run.getSettings()`. By this, the function is run.

   - I think that this is the reason of your issue.
2. About `alert(google.script.run.getSettings)` and `var settings = google.script.run.getSettings`, `google.script.run` returns no value. So in this case, `withSuccessHandler` is used.
3. `google.script.run` is run with the asynchronous process.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your Javascript as follows.

```
function save() {
  var url = document.getElementById('webhook-url').value
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
      alert(e);
      google.script.host.close();
    }).getSettings();
  }).saveSettings(url);
}

function get() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(settings => {
    document.getElementById('webhook-url').value = settings;
  }).getSettings();
}
```

- When above script is used, at first, the value is retrieved from `getSettings` by `get()`, and when the value is inputted and click button, the value is put by `saveSettings()` and the current value is retrieved by `getSettings()` and `alert()` is run, and then, `google.script.host.close()` is run.

#### Note:

- This is a simple modification. So please modify it for your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Nice answer but I think you code has an error: The first `withSuccessHandler` (of `saveSettings`) is missing the function declaration (either a regular or an arrow one)

Comment: @Martí Thank you for your comment. You are correct. That is due to my copy and paste mistake. In this case, In the current script, the inner `google.script.run` is firstly run. At first, I have thought to propose like `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {alert(e); google.script.host.close();}).getSettings).saveSettings(url);`. But from your comment, I think that this is also low readability. By your comment, I could modify the script using the arrow function. Thank you for your support.